# errors calling two actionFunctions in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to call 2 methods from my controller within the VF apex code. Having no end of issues.

Here's my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController" action="{!SendEnvelope}">
    <apex:form >

        <apex:actionFunction action="{!SendEnvelope}" name="SendEnvelope" oncomplete="EmbeddedSign();" />        
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!EmbeddedSign}" name="EmbeddedSign"/>    
        <apex:pageMessages />           
    </apex:form>
           <script>
              EmbeddedSign();   //oncomplete="EmbeddedSign();"
        </script>   
</apex:page>
```

I get that having *action="{!SendEnvelope}"* in the root page level will negate my actionFunction, but that's the only way i could get it working.

I've tried the following and failed:

**ERROR: 'Attempt to de-reference a null object'**

```
<script>           
      SendEnvelope();            
      EmbeddedSign();
</script>
```

Or simply having a 'main' function within my controller that in call in apex.

**ERROR: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out**

```
public PageReference Main() {
SendEnvelope();
EmbeddedSign();
}
```

So my assumption based on researching is that i need two separate transactions (callout ordering issues). That's why i have two functions that i need to call separately.

The above code actually gets it working, but it just keeps on reloading and reloading. i'm guessing it's because i'm missing 'rerender', but i couldn't get them working.

I briefly tried @future - that could be my solution, but i needed to return PageReference for the redirect to work in the second function (EmbeddedSign). Although am open to alternatives for sure.

I've hit a wall here, been trying to debug this for way too long. If anyone can please take a look at my code and provide suggestions that would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: I think Queueable class should work in your scenario.You can enqueue the Job however make sure that your job doesn't modify the same record.

Comment: Thanks. Would you care to elaborate? Does my apex code look ok? Do you want to see my controller class? I'm fairly new to apex, thanks

Comment: welcome to SFSE; this question is a bit unclear -- each time an actionFunction is invoked, there is a transaction with the server. If both functions need to be in the same transaction, then your controller method needs to do both operations as an atomic unit.  Please use [edit] to clarify

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I tried running both actions as one transaction, but got the "You have uncommitted work pending. " Error. So is my understanding correct that they need to be in separate transactions? ( I really just want it to work, if it's 1 transaction or 2, doesn't matter)